# Android Autoreply Application

Tags: android, sms

I am creating an android application that will send automatic replies to sms received from others if the user is busy. There will be two options for the user to select his status-available or busy. So once the user sets his status as busy, all the incoming sms's will receive an automatic reply (via sms) telling them that" I cant reply, I am busy". I am stuck on one condition though. I also have to make sure that after sending autoreply to that number if I again get an sms from the same number I should not autoreply back to that number if the time interval between two sms's recieved from that number is less than 10 mins and if the time interval exceeds 10 mins, it should send an autoreply. I dont know how to go about this. Can someone explain me the logic about how to code this and also what to use to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not posting any code, you can take this approach

- Have a Listener to scan incoming SMS's (lots of code available on stackoverflow)
- Get the number from the SMS, check if its a valid number (SMSs do come from network providers, no point replying to them)
- Keep a database of phonenumbers for each day,  keep adding numbers into it (Also add a field of time with it)
- Compare the incoming SMS number with your database, if found  and less than 10 min no action, else add to database and send a message. (keep updating time in your database for a number received)

Hope you have got some idea..

Answer (score 0):

I just updated Royston Pinto's answer to some level::

- Have a Listener to scan incoming SMS's (lots of code available on stackoverflow)
- Get the number from the SMS, check if its a valid number (SMSs do come from network providers, no point replying to them)
- Keep a entry of incoming message's phonenumbers and time into a **HashMap**
- Compare the incoming SMS number with your HashMap, if found  and less than 10 min no action, else add to HashMap and send a message.
- Update HashMap by checking periodically the time entry. If time past that entry is more than 10 minutes than delete that entry from HashMap(U can make a function for this and it call it from Handler every minute or so)

See 3rd n 5th point..